# I want to hide the bar which shows battery status,Time,Carrirer from application

Tags: ipad, ios4

how to hide the bar from application which shows battery status,Time,Carrier signal? is it status bar or anything else

Comment: ... and that bar is called as *Status Bar*!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is indeed the statusBar. You can hide it with this line (preferably in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: i have tried it but my application contains videos when i switch my screen to full screen and once again came to normal screen the status bar is still there

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if you use `setStatusBarHidden:YES` you will get:

> 'setStatusBarHidden:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 3.2

Instead use:

```
BOOL statusBarHidden = NO;

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return statusBarHidden;
}

// Hide the status bar.
-(IBAction)foo:(id)sender
{
    statusBarHidden = NO;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should create the the info.plist item `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` and set it to YES.